# How to use ValidationSummary only for messages that are not listed in the ValidationMessageFor blocks in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I wana show validation warnings by ValidationMessageFor and in the ValidationSummary show only other global warnings (wrong password for instance). But the input validation warnings are displaying in the ValidationSumary too, so user can see the same warnings on two places. How to solve it?

Comment: Use `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

Comment: Thats it. Thanks Stephen. I'll add it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use @Html.ValidationSummary(true)